# Collect delivery event data for specific email using Eloqua API

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

Using export definitions of `Eloqua BULK API`, I am collecting email statistics. I am able to check the delivery rate for specific email using sent, soft bounce, and hard bounce values on Eloqua dashboard.

I want to collect information for the contacts to whom the email was delivered using `Eloqua API`. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total successful sent count by using API to retrieve an email deployment statics.

Please refer [the link](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-REST-2.0-assets-email-deployment-%7Bid%7D-get.html).

Hope that helps you!